# title: Number of cases where blue color appears in the background color Error while implementing with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, combinations

explain problem:
When you click the button, the background color changes randomly.
I am trying to count the number of cases where the color blue appears.

summarize the problem:
The number of color arrays and the number of blues are not output.
I don't know how to implement 4C2 in JavaScript

Describe tried:
I tried to check the number of arrays in console.log in advance
Analyze the code of https://craftjj.neocities.org/index.1.html
I've been trying to find a way to implement combinations in javascript.

```
const body = document.querySelector('body')
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
const cBtn = document.querySelector('.cbtn')

const color = ['red','blue','pink','blue','yellow']

function conbination(){
    const colorNum = color.length//color배열 개수[color array count]
    const blueNum = color['blue'].length//blue개수[blue count]
    console.log(colorNum)
    console.log(blueNum)
}

/*const n = 4
const r = 2

function c(n, r) {
    return Math.floor(p(n, r) / times(1,r));
}
*/
    btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
        body.style.backgroundColor = color[n]
    })


function init(){
    cBtn.addEventListener('click',conbination)
}
```

Comment: I have hard time understanding what is the actual problem you are facing? In the code I see no attempt to calculate how many times the color blue was randomly chosen. So what do you want to do and what is the problem? You do have an error in the conbination-function, the second line will throw an exception since undefined does not have length-property. Not sure what you wanted it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const combination=function(n,k){
  let nfact=1,kfact=1;
  for(let i=n;i>n-k;i--){
    nfact*=i;
  }
  for(let i=k;i>0;i--){
    kfact*=i;
  }
  return Math.floor(nfact/kfact);
}
```

This will give you the roundoff value of combination for C(n,k)...